# SignalR in Windows app

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Please, could anybody show an example how to implement signalR in windows app.
i need to show a message box when server side is started
thnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Start method of the connection is an asynchronous method. You have to call ConinueWith method of the Task class.

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:port-no");
IHubProxy hub = connection.CreateProxy("hub-name");
connection.Start().ContinueWith((t) => { MessageBox.Show("Your-message"); });
```